# Build in function for plotting bayes decision boundary given the probability function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Is there a function in python, that plots bayes decision boundary if we input a function to it? I know there is one in matlab, but I'm searching for some function in python. I know that one way to achieve this is to iterate over the points, but I am searching for a built-in function.
I have bivariate sample points on the axis, and I want to plot the decision boundary in order to classify them.

Comment: So that we can find what you are looking for, what is the equivalent `matlab` function?

Comment: I don't remember the name of the function..but i used to use it some years back. Also thanks for trying

Comment: Is the matlab function here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/bq_679x-24.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off the guess of Chris in the comments above, I'm assuming you want to cluster points according to the Gaussian Mixture model - a reasonable method assuming the underlying distribution is a linear combination of Gaussian distributed samples. Below I've shown an example using `numpy` to create a sample data set, `sklearn` for it's GM modeling and `pylab` to show the results.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from sklearn import mixture

# Create some sample data
def G(mu, cov, pts):
    return np.random.multivariate_normal(mu,cov,500)

# Three multivariate Gaussians with means and cov listed below
MU  = [[5,3], [0,0], [-2,3]]
COV = [[[4,2],[0,1]], [[1,0],[0,1]], [[1,2],[2,1]]]

A = [G(mu,cov,500) for mu,cov in zip(MU,COV)]
PTS = np.concatenate(A) # Join them together

# Use a Gaussian Mixture model to fit
g = mixture.GMM(n_components=len(A))
g.fit(PTS)

# Returns an index list of which cluster they belong to
C = g.predict(PTS)

# Plot the original points
X,Y = map(array, zip(*PTS))
subplot(211)
scatter(X,Y)

# Plot the points and color according to the cluster
subplot(212)
color_mask = ['k','b','g']
for n in xrange(len(A)):
    idx = (C==n)
    scatter(X[idx],Y[idx],color=color_mask[n])
show()
```

[image]

See the [sklearn.mixture example](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm.html#example-mixture-plot-gmm-py) page for more detailed information on the classification methods.